# Running into SqlNullValueException: Data is Null on .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I a, running the following code to validate user login. But the program keeps on running into the error *SqlNullValueException: Data is Null.* I have done some research and most of it suggests that I get rid of the [Required] attribute on the properties - Username and Password. I have done so but the error is still persistent.

Below is the model

```
    [NotMapped]
    public class LoginViewModel

    {
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username Required")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

[image: The Repository for the Validation:]

Registration Model as below

[image: The Registration class:]

What is the best approach to such an issue.

Comment: check your connection string .. it seems your db context is null

Comment: What relevance does the LoginViewModel have here? Was it pasted in error? Your registration model still has required attributes? What does the data in the table look like? Long story short somewhere in the table you probably have a null value in a column where youve promised EF it won't be null (because you marked it as Required). If you're storing plaintext passwords a) don't and b) obscure them before you upload a screenshot of them if you don't fix them first

Comment: @Asham not sure how a null context would throw a sql null exception.. Are you thinking of NullReferenceException?

Comment: @CaiusJard Even after getting rid of the [Required] on the columns, the error is still persistent

Comment: What's the structure on the DB side of it?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan Both Username and password are marked as NOT NULL

Comment: @Nickson Any other columns?

Comment: There are quite a number (basically KYOC columns) but these two are the most significant at the moment.

Comment: *Even after getting rid of the [Required] on the columns* - mmm, but you said that and then showed us a ViewModel with those attribs, and a viewmodel isn't(shouldn't) be anything to do with the database.. Also, we've only seen a snippet of the Registration entity; what if it has other props that are NULL in the DB and Reuired on the C# side.  How about a different approach: scaffold the existing DB to a new place, and then use a diff tool to compare differences between your "doesnt work" context/entities and the one just scaffolded. Tell us what the diffs are

Answer (score 0):

You need to check in your DB whether there exists User record with the credentials you are providing to fetch the User Record. Seems to me either the User record is not present or the Credentials are not matching.

Comment: Those records do exist. On wrong password entry, a notification is issued however if the password is correct, then I bump into that error

Comment: in that case could you try using firstordefault instead of singleordefault? , the error could be popping out from the method singleordefault if there are more than one records matching to your credentials, it expects exactly one record to match

Answer (score 0):

try to change your model properties to

```
    [NotMapped]
public class LoginViewModel

{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username Required")]
    public string? Username { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password Required")]
    public string? Password { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable nullable reference types (string) by deleting the line
`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`
in the .NET 6 .csproj file.It is added by default as from .NET 6