# How Can I bypass the Concurrency Exception in NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am running into the following error whenever I am trying to update a row within a specific Table(Incidence)

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was
> expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually
> affected 0 row(s);

After debugging I realized that my ID `RegistrationID` is being passed as value 0 instead of the actual value in the db.

Code from Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditTicket(int? RegistrationID)
{
    if (RegistrationID == null)
    {
        return StatusCode(400);
    }
    Incidence incidence = await _context.Incidence.FindAsync(RegistrationID);
    if (incidence == null)
    {
        return StatusCode(404);
    }
    return View(incidence);
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditTicket(IList<IFormFile> Files, Incidence incidence)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(incidence.EmailAddress))
        {
            _context.Entry(incidence).Property(x1 => x1.DateServed).IsModified = false;
            _context.Entry(incidence).Property(x1 => x1.Source).IsModified = false;
            _context.Entry(incidence).State = EntityState.Modified;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();  // <= Exception occurs here
           ... 
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676084/entity-framework-core-database-operation-expected-to-affect-1-rows-but-actual) but did not work either.

Comment: What is the value of incidence.RegistrationId in the HttpPost handler ?

Comment: This isn't an exception you "bypass". It's an indication of a bug in your code and you resolve the situation by finding and fixing the bug.

Comment: @CaiusJard the value is 0

Comment: So, there you have your answer; the database is getting 0 because you're giving 0. Now where is it coming from? Is the front end (the thing calling this endpoint) sending 0?

Comment: @CaiusJard I had mentioned that in my earlier post

Comment: Which earlier post? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604812/running-into-sqlnullvalueexception-data-is-null-on-net-6) ?

Comment: It is like the previous commenters said. If you pass 0 as the id of the object how should EF know which row to update?
You should start by solving the ID coming in 0.